# Powershell - replace object values with other object values as a group

Tags: powershell

I've got a list of objects in the variable $variables.

Each variable in $variables has the properties Name and Value.

As example.
$Variables[1] has the following properties:
Name:Test
Value: ${Test1}

$Variables[2]:
Name: Test1
Value: Thisistheteststring.

I need to output the variable values and the syntax ${Test1} means that should inherit the value from the variable named Test1.

I know I can loop through all of the variables and replace the value one at a time but is there a way to replace those values in bulk.  So if I get a list/array of variables that have ${*} in them I'd like to then use the array of variables don't have that as a value as a lookup to replace the ${*} with the value.

Output would be:
$Variables[1]
Name:Test
Value: Thisistheteststring.

$Variables[2]:
Name: Test1
Value: Thisistheteststring.

Preferably avoiding looping through all the variables over and over to achieve it.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Have you looked into [Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) ?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# Sample input objects.
$objects = @(
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'Test'
    Value = '${Test1}'
  },
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'Test1'
    Value = 'Thisisthestring'
  }
)

# Split the object collection into those objects that have their own values
# ($sourceObjects) and those that reference other objects ($refObjects)
$refObjects, $sourceObjects  = $objects.Where(
  { $_.Value -match '^\$\{.+}$' }, 
  'Split'
)

# Build an aux. hashtable that maps each source object's .Name property value 
# to its .Value property value.
$ht = @{}
foreach ($sourceObject in $sourceObjects) {
  $ht[$sourceObject.Name] = $sourceObject.Value
}

# Loop over the referencing objects and replace the .Value property
# of each with that of the referenced (source) object, using the hashtable.
foreach ($refObject in $refObjects) {
  $refObject.Value = $ht[($refObject.Value -replace '\W')]
}

# Output the modified objects.
$objects
```

Output:

```
Name  Value
----  -----
Test  Thisisthestring
Test1 Thisisthestring
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Going to test it out today.  I haven't seen the split option on where before and can't find that in the documentation.  I found an example [here](https://thomasrayner.ca/quick-tip-split-a-powershell-collection-into-two-arrays/) but can't seem to find it in the official powershell documentation.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bee_Riii. It's not easy to find. `.ForEach()` and `.Where()`, as _intrinsic methods_, are now mentioned _in the abstract_ in the conceptual [about_Intrinsic_Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) help topic, and _described in detail_ in  [about_Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where)